# Managing Vim plugins

Tags: vim, plugins

What's the best way to manage Vim plugins? Some plugins use Vimball, but I read somewhere that it was seriously broken, and manually dropping each plugin into ~/.vim/ results in a mess of files that are near impossible to update or organise. Is there a plugin-manager for Vim that functions similarly to Linux package managers? Or can plugins be reorganised into their own directories to make administering them easier?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458398/packageplugin-management-for-vim maybe?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To reorganize plugins in their own directories, [pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) is quite popular.

See a [blog post detailing the installation](http://tammersaleh.com/posts/the-modern-vim-config-with-pathogen) or a [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/synchronizing-plugins-with-git-submodules-and-pathogen/) from Drew Neil.

This is what I actually use. It basically puts each plugin in its separate directory, so you can easily add or remove them.

Comment: +1 Pathogen does a great job.

Comment: Steve Losh has an article about this and more http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/

Answer (score 51):

There is a new splendid tool, vundle, found here : https://github.com/gmarik/vundle

It is **Awesome**, like a wedding of pathogen with git.

Comment: If you like vundle you should check out NeoBundle: https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim. It's a fork of vundle that has more features and addresses some performance concerns.

Comment: But... What if the plugin doesn't exist in git... What if it is svn? or hg?

Comment: Can vundle handle those cases?

Comment: It seems it doesn't handle these cases. Most of the time, scripts are mirrored on http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html so that you only have to supply the script name in your vimrc.

Comment: Even with its file:// syntax it still wants to fetch from github, which may be blocked in corporate networks... should use the .zip.

Answer (score 6):

I personally prefer [vim-addon-manager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2905): it installs each plugin into separate directory, is able to download and update them. Documentation of vim-addon-manager contains some references to related projects, you may also want to try them.

Answer (score 1):

Matthew Weier O'Phinney, PHP Zend Framework project lead, writes a little about it.
Maybe you will find it useful: http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/249-Vim-Toolbox,-2010-Edition.html

Answer (score 1):

Pathogen has already been mentioned as a way of managing plugins.

A way of enhancing this is to add the extra plugins as git submodules (or whatever your VCS of choice is). This makes it easier to keep up to date, and easier to replicate when using other machines.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/mattsacks/dotfiles) from github.

Comment: I like the idea of using git to manage the plugins, but the github example is not very self-explanatory to me. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: 404 on the example link.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [NeoBundle](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim), the ultimate package manager for vim. It's a fork of [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle).

Comment: NeoBundle ended. Should it be also removed from answers?

Answer (score 0):

I use [this script](http://artmees.github.io/gitsubmodule/) for updating and removing vim pathogen plugins

Answer (score 0):

With [NeoBundle](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim) fall [Dein](https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim) takes it place with features like:

- being faster;
- async support;
- probably would add support for `hg` and `svn`.